Searching in a list in C
I am trying to write this code for my class, when I use the searchByName function it works correctly, but then I use searchByCity and the output is the same as the first function, even if I search for a different thing in the list.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct rubrica {
    char name[30];
    char number[10];
    char address[30];
    struct rubrica *next;
} typedef rubrica;

rubrica *createList() {
    char name[30];
    char number[30];
    char address[30];

    printf("type the name of first contact\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("type the number of first contact\n");
    scanf("%s", number);
    printf("type the address of first contact\n");
    scanf("%s", address);
    
    rubrica *head = (rubrica *)malloc(sizeof(rubrica)); 

    strcpy(head->name, name);
    strcpy(head->number, number);
    strcpy(head->address, address);

    head->next = NULL;

    return head;
}

rubrica *nextNode(rubrica *head) {
    char name[30], number[30], address[30];
    int true = 0;

    do {
        printf("insert contact name\n");
        scanf("%s", name);
        if (strcmp(name, head->name) == 0) {
            printf("the name is already registered in the list\n");
        } else {
            true = 1;
        }
    } while (true != 1);
    
    printf("insert contact number\n");
    scanf("%s", number);
    printf("insert contact number\n");
    scanf("%s", address);

    rubrica *new = NULL;
    new = (rubrica *)malloc(sizeof(rubrica));

    strcpy(new->name, name);
    strcpy(new->number, number);
    strcpy(new->address, address);

    new->next = head;

    head = new;
    return head;
}

rubrica *searchByName(rubrica *head, char search[]) {
    rubrica *found;
    while (head != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(search, head->name) == 0) {
            found = head;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }

    return found;
}

rubrica *searchByCity(rubrica *head, char search[]) {
    rubrica *found;

    do {
        if (strcmp(search, head->address) == 0) {
            found = head;
        }

        head = head->next;

    } while (head != NULL);

    return found;
}

int main(void) {
    char search[100];
    int s;
    rubrica *head = createList();
    rubrica *searchNode;

    do {
        printf("inserisci la tua scelta da tastiera:\n"
               " 0 - esci dal programma \n"
               " 2 - inserisci un nuovo contatto nella rubrica \n"
               " 3 - ricerca nella rubrica per nome\n"
               " 4 - ricerca nella rubrica per città\n");
        scanf("%d\n", &s);

        switch (s) {
        case 0:
            break;

        case 2: {
            head = nextNode(head);
            for (head = head; head != NULL; head = head->next) {
                printf("%s\n", head->name);
                printf("%s\n", head->number);
                printf("%s\n", head->address);
            }
            break;
          }

        case 3: {
            printf("type the name of the contact you wanna search in the list\n");
            scanf("%s", search);
            searchNode = searchByName(head, search);
            printf("%s\n", searchNode->number);
            break;
          }

        case 4: {
            printf("type the address of the contact you wanna search in the list\n");
            scanf("%s", search);

            searchByCity(head, search);
            printf("%s %s\n", searchNode->number, searchNode->name);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                search[i] = '\0';
            }
            break;
          }

        default: {
            printf("il valore inserito non è valido, ritenta\n");
            break;
          }
        }
    } while (s != 0);
    
    return 0;
}

Also, ignore the fact that some of the outputs are still in Italian, I translated some things to make the code understandable.
I tried to reset the search string every time I use it, but nothing changes.
Also I think it's an "order" thing, that the search string kinda gets stuck with the previous value, cause I tried to print the nodes I inserted previously, and they are correct.

If the search term isn't in the list, your search code returns an uninitialized variable, which is Undefined Behaviour. Try rubrica *found = NULL;

Why does searchByCity use a do { } while loop? It should use a while loop like searchByName otherwise it would crash if the list is empty.

You are not assigning the return value from the call to searchByCity to the searchNode variable. (searchNode = searchByCity(...);).

Note that searchByName and searchByCity could be changed to return as soon as a matching node is found rather than iterating through the remainder of the list.

You can replace your loop that sets the bytes of search to \0 with a single memset(search, 0, sizeof(search)) call.

There's no need to clear search after using it. scanf() will overwrite whatever is there.

But if addresses can contain multiple words, you shouldn't use %s to read it. That just reads one word.

@Barmar or at least use width specifiers with %s and scanf.

Unrelated bug: What happens if someone enters a field with more than 29 characters or a search term with more than 99 characters? (For a partial fix, recall that scanf format specifiers can take a maximum field length prefix, e.g. %42s)

@Neeks: you can accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

You forgot to assign the returned value of the function searchByCity(head, search) to the variable searchNode. When you search using searchByName you set the variable to the corresponding value, and that value persists even when you call the function searchByCity (without updating it).
Use searchNode = searchByCity(head, search); and it will solve the issue.

There are multiple problems:

the program never checks for allocation failure.
the return value of scanf() is never tested: this causes undefined behavior on invalid or missing input.
scanf("%s", name) causes undefined behavior if more than 29 characters are entered.  You should limit the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array: scanf("%29s", name)
the number local array has a length of 30 while the structure field with the same name has a length of 10. This is inconsistent and may cause undefined behavior in strcpy if more than 9 characters have been entered.
specifying typedef after the structure definition is considered bad style.
nextNode only checks the head node for an identical name. You should use searchByName to check the whole list.
found is uninitialized in searchByName and searchByCity.  You should initialize this variable to NULL to avoid undefined behavior if no node is found.
scanf("%d\n", &s) will keep reading characters after the number until more input is read after the newline. Remove the \n and check the return value, which must be 1.
the option 2 will iterate the list of nodes using the head pointer: the head pointer will be NULL after this loop and the list is no longer accessible. Use a separate pointer for this loop.
in case 3, printf("%s\n", searchNode->number) will cause undefined behavior if no matching node is found.
in case 4, the return value of searchByCity(head, search) is not stored.  The last value of searchNode is used, which may be invalid as this variable is uninitialized. The loop to clear the search array is useless.
the list is not freed at the end of the program.

